# Implement type variables in C

Tags: c, haskell, types

I'm writing in C and would like to have some implementation of type variables.  In Haskell for example I could write something like:

```
data Matrix a = Matrix [a] Int Int
```

which would let me define matrices with entries of any type 'a'.  In C, I've written for each type some structure:

```
struct zMatrix {
  int dim_row;
  int dim_col;
  int *coords;
};

struct rMatrix {
  int dim_row;
  int dim_col;
  float *coords;
};

...
```

Is there some way to have a generic matrix structure and some function to create a matrix which would specify the type of the coords field? Something like:

```
struct matrix {
  int dim_row;
  int dim_col;
  (typevar type) *coords;
};

struct matrix matrixCreate(typevar type, int n, int m){...};
struct matrix M = matrixCreate(int, 3, 3);
struct matric M = matrixCreate(float, 3, 3);
...
```

Comment: You can have a `void*`, or a `union` of multiple types. Whether that is a good idea is a different question. C is not Haskell, treating it as if it were will be extraordinarily painful.

Comment: If you have a limited amount of types `a`, you can also use macros to generate the `int,float,..` variants for you without repeating everything. Functions can be made generic in a type safe way using `_Generic`. Still, I think it is not very idiomatic in C to do that: instead of pushing hard to achieve a 100% type safe interface fighting against the simplicity of the C type system (e.g. no parametric types), it's more common to opt for the basic option of using `void *` and casts, even if this is not so type-safe and puts more burden on the user (which has to be sure the casts will be OK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it. As @EOF mentioned, you can use a union type for the portion of the structure that is different for different data types. You'll probably want to store something representing the type in the structure as well. You can't pass a type name to a function as in your example, but you can define an enum that represents the various types. You would then use switch statements to implement any type-specific code. An alternative to using switch statements is to use a data structure which describes a type (this would contain function pointers and possibly other information). You would declare an instance of that data structure for each type and your type-specific code would use information in the appropriate type's data structure to do what it needs to do. The type data structures could be in an array which you would index with the type enum value, or you could use a pointer to the type data structure to represent the type.

If C++ is an option, that would make this a lot easier.